# Use templates to read vector

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm trying to read a vector from file but I might have different datatype there and I use templates

```
template <class T>
vector<T> readd(int n)
{
    vector<T> V;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        T k;
        fin>>k;
        V.push_back(k);
    }
    return V;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> V;
    int n;
    fin>>n;
    V = readd(n);
}
```

But I've got compile error

> error: no matching function for call to `readd(int&)`

Can someone help me...

Comment: I need return statement.

Comment: You actually return a `std::vector<T>` so why would want a second teplate parameter? Either directly write `std::vector<T> readd(vector<T> V)` or write `auto readd(vector<V> V) -> decltype(V)`

Comment: I suck at C++ but don't you have to call it like readd<int>(V,n) assuming we trash template U.

Comment: `template <class T>
vector<T> readd(int n)
{
    //cout<<typeid(T).name()<<endl;
    vector<T> V;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        T k;
        fin>>k;
        V.push_back(k);
    }
    return V;
}`
...
`V = readd(n);`

This one also doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use template argument deduction, but in order for that to work the compiler needs to be able to deduce every template argument from the types of the arguments you pass to the function. U does not appear in your argument list, so the compiler cannot deduce its type.

That said, it doesn't make any sense to pass a vector by value to this function since you immediately clear it. The canonical way to write your function would be

```
template <class T>
std::vector<T> readd(int n)
{
    std::vector<T> v;
    v.reserve(k); // prevent unnecessary reallocation
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        T k;
        fin >> k;
        v.push_back(k);
    }
    return v;
}
```

and then call it like

```
std::vector<int> v = readd<int>(10);
```

You need to specify the template argument, because it cannot be deduced by the compiler.

Also, in case fin is a global variable, it would be better to make it non-global and pass it to the read function.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return `V` which is nothing but `vector<T>`.

Do this:

```
template <class T>
vector<T> readd(int n)
{
    vector<T> V;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        T k;
        fin>>k;
        V.push_back(k);
    }
    return V;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> V;
    int n;
    fin>>n;
    //you need to tell the compiler the actual type of T since it is not auto deducible!
    V = readd<int>(n); 
}
```

Comment: The problem is if I don't pass vector as a parameter it doesn't work.
Sorry for the n, I've just forgotten to copy it here

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Anyways, I am not asking you to remove the parameter, what I am just recommending is to pass `V` as a reference!

Comment: The new version:
`vector<T> readd(int n)`
and error 
`error: no matching function for call to ‘readd(int&)’`

Comment: Would you mind reposting your so-called _new version_ ?